# Limit create repository to project?

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to give an external team rights to manage repositories inside a specified project and no other?

I don't want the external team to have visibility or rights to do anything else outside an assigned project.

Comment: Bitbucket server or cloud?

Comment: I believe its cloud.